# Preprocess a twig template file

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I don't fully understand how preprocessing works

I have a twig template `/themes/custom/client/templates/content/node--myfile.html.twig` that I want to alter

I want to show/hide a part of that template depending on a field `display` with the machine name `field_display` stored in the matching content type called `Project` and with the machine name `project_machine_name`.

So I well understand I have to use hooks in order to do this, but I don't understand how I am supposed to name the hook functionnality neither how I'm supposed to access the data stored from the content type into the hook to alter the template view.

I know the hooks goes into the `.module` file. Actually I already have some of them, but I don't understand them properly. The only things I know for sure is that the function name must start by the module name

```
function my_module_SOMETHING_SOMETHINGELSE() {

}
```

So the issue is: how to name the hook function in order to alter the template ? I guess I understand the name is some kind of standard structure which will tell drupal if the function needs to be called before a specific action.

How to retrieve data stored from the `display` field of the content-types `Project`?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocess hooks are named `MY_MODULE_preprocess_TEMPLATE_NAME`, in your case:

```
function my_module_preprocess_node__myfile(&$variables) {}
```

Notice how I replace the template's dashes with underscores in the function name.

Now you can get the `display` variable from `$variables['node']->field_display->value`.

Comment: Thanks but I wonder if there isn't something to do in order to make the hook effective. I've just set a var_dump in the my_module_preprocess_node__myfile but nothing is triggered when I go to the page.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: I didn't. It's fine now, thank you. I still need to look how i'm going to really alter the resulting html but that's an other issue.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped :)